# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: in C# but works fine in MySQL Workbench

Tags: c#, mysql

**Goal:**

I am trying to put a query into C# to update MySQL record for specific `id`. But it is coming with an error message whenever I run it.

**This is the Error message:**

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\', ''))), '\Archive\', SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\', -1)) where id = 2' at line 1'

**C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string query = "UPDATE document_control SET newIssueNo = 2, file_attachment = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\\', LENGTH(file_attachment) - LENGTH(REPLACE(file_attachment, '\\', ''))), '\\Archive\\', SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\\', -1)) where id = 2";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("credentials");
            conn.Open(); //Open the connection
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close(); //don't forget to close it after you're done



        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it in MySQL workbench:

```
UPDATE document_control SET newIssueNo = 2, file_attachment = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\\',  LENGTH(file_attachment) - LENGTH(REPLACE(file_attachment, '\\', ''))), '\\Archive\\', SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\\', -1)) where id = 2


1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the prior revisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@` before string value because in regular declaration `\` is escape character.

```cs
string query = @"UPDATE document_control SET newIssueNo = 2, file_attachment = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\\', LENGTH(file_attachment) - LENGTH(REPLACE(file_attachment, '\\', ''))), '\\Archive\\', SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_attachment, '\\', -1)) where id = 2";
```